# Stop ajax call within object

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, timeout

I have an object where I have an ajax request:

```
var newsrecentObj = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.fetch().done( function(data) {
            console.dir( data );
        } ).error( function(data) {
            // stop ajax call
        } );
    },

    fetch: function() {
        var self = this;

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://url.to/api',
            timeout: 5000,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }
}

var newsrecent = Object.create();
newsrecent.init();
```

I want to stop the request when a timeout occurs. But how can I do that?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

If your request timedout, it stopped alone because of the timeout.
By the way, you should handle this event, so look at the timeout property in the jQuery ajax documentation !
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stop the ajax request, you could create a reference to the jqxhr object, and call the .abort method.